# How to determine if JSON path is valid for a document

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

`ReadContext` interface does not expose a method that would verify if a given JSON path is valid for a document. Instead, `read()` method would throw `PathNotFoundException` if the path does not exist. Why there is no method like `isPathValid()` that would return `boolean`. I am using this approach to classify my JSON payloads. Is there another way to check if a specific path exists without catching an exception?

Comment: `file.exists()`?

Comment: not if a file exists, but if the json document contains json path inside of it.